# Regular expression splitting by a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string `str='\n1. AA \n2. BB\n3.\n4. CC'`. I want to split it using the following pattern: a newline character followed by a digit followed by one or more space(s).

I am hoping to get the answer `['','AA ', 'BB\n3.', 'CC']`.

If I use `re.split('\n[0-9]\.\s+',str)`, I get the result:

```
['', 'AA ', 'BB', '4. CC']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`\s+` at the end matches whitespace *including newline characters*. If you don't want trailing newlines to match change it to `[^\S\n]+`:

```
>>> re.split('\n[0-9]\.[^\S\n]+',s)
['', 'AA ', 'BB\n3.', 'CC']
```